# Mac PHP7 Pecl Oauth : Couldn't find pcre.h

Tags: php, macos, oauth, pcre, pecl

i passed my day to fix this error and i think it's time to ask a question!

so i got this error when i try to install the Oauth PHP module with
`sudo pecl install oauth`

`configure: error: Couldn't find pcre.h, try installing the libpcre development/headers package`

I've installed pcre with Brew cause i'm on Mac Os 10.11.6

Pcre is correctly installed :

`iLolo:oauth-2.0.2 do_f$ brew install pcre
 Warning: pcre-8.39 already installed`

PHP Version :

`iLolo:oauth-2.0.2 do_f$ php -v
PHP 7.0.8 (cli) (built: Jun 26 2016 12:30:44) ( NTS )`

Here there is the locate pcre.h command

```
iLolo:~ do_f$ locate pcre.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-migrator/sdk/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h
/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.39/include/pcre.h
/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.39/share/doc/pcre/html/pcre.html
/usr/local/include/pcre.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/pcre.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/php/ext/pcre/pcre.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/php/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/php/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre.h.back
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/php/ext/pcre.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/php/include/pcre.h
/usr/local/php5-7.0.8-20160626-123411/include/php/pcre.h
iLolo:~ do_f$
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So i've find a "solution", i've edit the `configure` inside the src dir     oauth-2.0.2

```
#ac_fn_c_check_header_mongrel "$LINENO" "pcre.h" "ac_cv_header_pcre_h"  "$ac_includes_default" 
#if test "x$ac_cv_header_pcre_h" = xyes; then : 
#else # as_fn_error $? "Couldn't find pcre.h, try installing the libpcre development/headers package" "$LINENO" 5 
#fi
```

then i've do `./configure` `make` `make test` `make install` and i add `extension=oauth.so` in the `php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

Install pcre:

`brew install pcre`

Then run again.

Answer (score -1):

You need the `pcre-devel` package installed. Opening the configure script and commenting out the check is not your answer.

```
brew install pcre-devel
```

And, then try again.